# Finding the second last occurrence of a string (date) in Regex

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I got the following strings:

```
(1640.31; 08/19/2016; 09/13/2016;); (250000.0; 09/30/2016; 02/17/2018;); (100000.0; 03/12/2018; 12/31/2025;);
```

Or

```
(1000000.0; 05/30/2018; 06/03/2028;);
```

I need to return this second to last date, so in these cases for example 1: 03/12/2018 and example 2: 05/30/2018.

Because there are a lot of string-parts ending with ; I can't figure quite out how I can get the second to last date.

Comment: are dates always `mm/dd/yyyy;` with precisely 2, 2 and 4 digits, forward slash separator, semicolon terminated?

Comment: `\(.+; ([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}); ([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4});\);`

Will give three groups, (outer, first and second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '(1640.31; 08/19/2016; 09/13/2016;); (250000.0; 09/30/2016; 02/17/2018;); (100000.0; 03/12/2018; 12/31/2025;);' AS str UNION ALL
  SELECT '(1000000.0; 05/30/2018; 06/03/2028;);'
)
SELECT ARRAY_REVERSE(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, r'\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d'))[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] dt
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result:

```
Row dt   
1   03/12/2018   
2   05/30/2018
```

note: above assumes that dates are always in mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy format, but can be adjusted if different

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
select (select array_agg(val order by o desc limit 2)  -- the limit is just for efficiency
        from unnest(split(str, ';')) val with offset o
        where val like '%/%/%'
       )[ordinal(2)] a
from (select '1640.31; 08/19/2016; 09/13/2016;' as str) x;
```

Note that this also (happens to) work with parentheses, if they are really part of the strings.